# ssh tunnel do not work for mssql_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server

Why mssql_connect() can not connect to mssql database with tunnel.

I have created tunnel for remote server like:

```
$ssh -L 1433:db_server:1433 user@mid_server
```

This forward the local port 1433 to db_server. I tested.

However when I try to connect to database using php it does not work

```
mssql_connect("localhost:1433", 'db_user', 'db_password')
```

Detail (edited):

1. db_server : Remote database server where sql server is installed. DB server has firewall. Only mid_server can connect
2. mid_server : Middle where which is allowed to connect db_server

Comment: have you try this to connect with php with this login details?

Comment: Sorry... I tried to connect with Navicat while tunnel is on. It connect with same user/pwd with Navicat.

Comment: Just checking: is the webserver on localhost?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: PHP Warning:  mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server

Comment: Are you sure your dbengine is listening on port 1433 ?

Comment: schmit007 yes sure. I said above, I connect with Navicat with same credential with tunneling on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed it by make some changes on freetds.conf

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 4.2
```

to

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
tds version = 7.0
```

and restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are connecting from a linux (or MacOS) box to MSSQL server, probably using freetds connector. Two things need to be checked: if the server is properly listening to the port and if FreeTDS is properly installed on the Linux machine. Since you can connect with another client, the problem should be on FreeTDS.

Make sure FreeTDS is installed and properly configured. Try to connect to the server directly with (it should prompt for password):

```
# tsql -S localhost -U db_user
```

If necessary, adjust the port/locale/version information on freetds.conf. For more information:

- http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm
- http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/confirminstall.htm#TSQL

Comment: I got following reply "Error 20009 (severity 9):
 Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
 OS error 61, "Connection refused"